# How to get number of views of a blog post?

Tags: 2013, development, analytics

I am writing server-side code to get the number of likes for each item in the Post list for each site.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl);
int countBlogs = 0;
int countPosts = 0;

foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
    {
        if(list.Title == "Posts")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BLOG FOUND by" + list.Author);
            countBlogs++;
            foreach (SPItem item in list.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1} \nLikes: {2} \n\n", item.ID, item["Title"], item["Number of Likes"]);
                countPosts++;
            }
        }       
    }  
}
Console.WriteLine("Total Blogs: {0} \nTotal Posts: {1} ", countBlogs, countPosts);
```

It is a basic iteration through all the Sites within a Site Collection.
I have searched a lot for a way to get the number of views for each blog post but I couldn't find something useful. The out of the box Popularity Trends is not exactly what I need. In the end, I want to display the top viewed items in the list Posts.

Comment: I followed your directions and I don't see the site analytics reports under Site Actions. Is this a configuration issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the blog site settings. Go to site actions Then site analytics reports then top pages.

Please refer to the below link:

[View and configure usage analytics reports in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2014/01/23/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

[How to find your document hits on SharePoint 2007](http://faraz-khan.blogspot.in/2008/02/how-to-find-your-document-hits-on.html)

[Find the most visited sites in SharePoint 2013](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-most-visited-sites-in-sharepoint-2013.html)